# How to dynamically modify Google Maps Heatmap locations with data from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use angular google maps:
https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/testapp/

Test data:
https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/testapp/taxi-data.js

Javascript example:

```
var taxiData = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
];
```

I do the query with AngularJS and retrieve Latitude and Longitude in list data[] for example.

How can I dynamically modify the code above so it "initializes" new google.maps.LatLng with my data from DB?

Example of what I had in my had in pseudocode:

```
var data = [];
var taxiData = [];
```

//angular call to store data, so we have data:

```
data = someCall..
```

Dynamically add instances into taxiData list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your db data is accessible via http get in json format ( in the below example the data is retrieved from [`taxiData.json` file](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/6d9c464ab034f5b93295)), the following example demonstrates how to initialize heatmap layer once the data is loaded.

**Example**

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
.controller("MapCtrl", function($scope,$http,NgMap){

  $scope.taxiData = [];

  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {

    $scope.taxiData = [];

    $http.get('https://rawgit.com/vgrem/6d9c464ab034f5b93295/raw/9ca3819aa8270823da64cba6f91d24945cc52940/taxiData.json').success(function(data) {
         $scope.taxiData = data.map(function(item){
             return new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng);
         });

         var layer = $scope.map.heatmapLayers.taxiDataMap;
         layer.setData($scope.taxiData);
    });
  });
 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>


<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ng-map zoom="13" center="37.774546, -122.433523" map-type-id="SATELLITE">
        <heatmap-layer id="taxiDataMap" data="taxiData"></heatmap>
    </ng-map>
  </div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/qg3k1ke7/1/)